# VB.net Recognize strings under 'a*'

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to Write a program to recognize strings under **'a*'**

PROGRAM LOGIC: By using transition diagram i want to verify input of the state. 
 If the state recognize  the given pattern rule. Then print string is accepted under a*      Else print string not accepted.

this is what i have tried

```
      Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\ba*\b")
      Dim match As Match = regex1.Match(txt_input.Text)
 If match.Success Then
        lbl_output.Text = txt_input.Text & " is accepted under rule 'a*'"
 Else
            lbl_output.Text = txt_input.Text & " is not recognized"
        End If
```

the problem is when i enter string like **saa** is will accept it. it allows any character to come before the character **a**.
i want it to accept only when the string contains the character a. for example a,aaa,aaa,

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the following regex:

```
^a+$
```

**Code:**

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^a+$")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("aaaa")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine("match")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("no match")
End If
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Your answer fails for regex.Match("").. It says "match" @SharmaHussein, plz test it well.

Comment: @MukulVarshney The OP was not clear with regard to whether empty string counts as only having `a` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\ba\S*\b")
```